# Relative layout - layout_toRightOf

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I started to convert TableLayout to RelativeLayout. Let's use A, B for columns and 1, 2 for rows. I set A2 *BELOW* A1 and B2 to *RIGHT* of A2. The problem is that A2 was displayed over A1 (e.g. in the first row)! I tried align_baseline set to A2 but it behaved same way. The solution was to set A2 *BELOW* A1.

Can you please explain me this behaviour, why I have to set *BELOW* attribute as well? I thought that I just need to set first column's elements below upper row and their neigbours will be sitting besides them.

PS I looked at questions that may already have my answer and similar questions.

Updated with the code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/firstOperand"
    style="@style/KeypadButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/firstOperand"
    android:text="+"
    android:id="@+id/operator"
    style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/operator"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/secondOperand"
    style="@style/KeypadButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/secondOperand"
    android:text="="
    android:id="@+id/equalView"
    style="@style/KeypadFunctionButton" />

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/equalView"
    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/resultView"
    style="@style/KeypadButton" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/firstOperand"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:onClick=""
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/seekBar"
    android:id="@+id/progressImage"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cat"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

I have to add following line to the progressImage otherwise the image is displayed over the operator button.

```
    android:layout_below="@id/firstOperand"
```

Comment: I'd be happy to answer this, but I'm not sure what you're asking. You said earlier that "Let's use A, B for columns and 1, 2 for rows. I set **A2 BELOW A1** and B2 to RIGHT of A2" yet later said that the solution was "o set A2 BELOW A1." What did you try first?

Comment: Also, if you post snippets of before vs after xml, it'll help out a ton~

Comment: See updated question. I wonder why layout_below is neccessary when layout_toRightOf is already there.

Comment: `layout_toRightOf` doesn't mean it will align respective layout from xy position.

Comment: So I have to define vertical alignment as well, do not I?

Comment: Answered~ Hope that clarifies this! RelativeLayout unfortunately takes some getting used to, as it's so different from other layouts- heck, you can even stack elements with "toRightOf" to way off the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way layout_toRightOf, layout_below, etc is that they align - for most Views - the top left corner of the View wherever you specified. Furthermore, the RelativeLayout attributes tend to affect the elements as little as possible- `toRightOf` simply moves the x-coordinate, `below` simply moves the y-coordinate, etc. For complex layouts, you'll tend to need 2 attributes bare minimum.

Personally, I tend to use `layout_alignTop`, `layout_alignLeft`, etc as they make far more intuitive sense.

This here is just an additional read in case you want to learn more about this particular ViewGroup: [Android User Interface Design: Relative Layouts](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-user-interface-design-relative-layouts--mobile-4301)

Answer (score 1):

In a relative layout, the layout_toRightOf attribute sets the horizontal coordinate of the element. So, you tell it to place it in the X axis to the right of the desired element. It sets that x coordinate and the element floats at the top as there's no guidance for the vertical position (let's say the y coordinate). Calling the layout_below sets that y coordinate.